# make error: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile, configure, autotools

Hello and thank you for your help in advance (I'm a bit of a newbie). I am on ubuntu 18.

I am trying to install an older version of some software called HepMC (need older version for project) and I had no problem installing the slightly newer version. When I try to build from source I get an error on the make command. I've seen this "all-recurive failed" error all over the web, but the solutions I've seen for other people have seemed to be very software specific and have not helped me.

I am not really sure how to interpret this error and I haven't been able to find a good answer. Any tips or suspicions on what might be going on here would be greatly appreciated. Been bashing my head against this for awhile

Before running make I did

```
autoreconf -i configure.ac
./configure
```

and this ran with no errors or warnings.

Here's the snippet where the error seems to begin, I'll attach the full printout from "make" down below.

```
In file included from ../HepMC/CommonIO.h:15:0,
                 from CommonIO.cc:11:
../HepMC/GenEvent.h:408:80: error: template argument 3 is invalid
    public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag,HepMC::GenParticle*,ptrdiff_t>{
                                                                                ^
../HepMC/GenEvent.h:459:71: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ was not declared in this scope
    public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag,HepMC::GenParticle*,ptrdiff_t>{
                                                                       ^~~~~~~~~
../HepMC/GenEvent.h:459:71: note: suggested alternatives:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/string:38:0,
                 from CommonIO.cc:8:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/c++config.h:232:28: note:   ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
   typedef __PTRDIFF_TYPE__ ptrdiff_t;
                            ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/c++config.h:232:28: note:   ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
In file included from ../HepMC/CommonIO.h:15:0,
                 from CommonIO.cc:11:
../HepMC/GenEvent.h:459:80: error: template argument 3 is invalid
    public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag,HepMC::GenParticle*,ptrdiff_t>{
                                                                                ^
CommonIO.cc: In member function ‘HepMC::HeavyIon* HepMC::CommonIO::read_heavy_ion(std::istream*)’:
CommonIO.cc:318:9: warning: converting ‘false’ to pointer type ‘HepMC::HeavyIon*’ [-Wconversion-null]
  return false;
         ^~~~~
CommonIO.cc:328:26: warning: converting ‘false’ to pointer type ‘HepMC::HeavyIon*’ [-Wconversion-null]
     if( nh == 0 ) return false;
                          ^~~~~
CommonIO.cc: In member function ‘HepMC::PdfInfo* HepMC::CommonIO::read_pdf_info(std::istream*)’:
CommonIO.cc:344:9: warning: converting ‘false’ to pointer type ‘HepMC::PdfInfo*’ [-Wconversion-null]
  return false;
         ^~~~~
CommonIO.cc:356:27: warning: converting ‘false’ to pointer type ‘HepMC::PdfInfo*’ [-Wconversion-null]
     if( id1 == 0 ) return false;
                           ^~~~~
CommonIO.cc: In member function ‘HepMC::GenVertex* HepMC::CommonIO::read_vertex(std::istream*, HepMC::TempParticleMap&)’:
CommonIO.cc:374:9: warning: converting ‘false’ to pointer type ‘HepMC::GenVertex*’ [-Wconversion-null]
  return false;
         ^~~~~
CommonIO.cc: In member function ‘HepMC::GenParticle* HepMC::CommonIO::read_particle(std::istream*, HepMC::TempParticleMap&)’:
CommonIO.cc:411:9: warning: converting ‘false’ to pointer type ‘HepMC::GenParticle*’ [-Wconversion-null]
  return false;
         ^~~~~
Makefile:478: recipe for target 'CommonIO.lo' failed
make[1]: *** [CommonIO.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/maxfieg/Desktop/FelixResearch/junk/hep_build2/HepMC2.04/src'
Makefile:397: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

and here's the full return of `make`

```
make
Making all in HepMC
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/maxfieg/Desktop/FelixResearch/junk/hep_build2/HepMC2.04/HepMC'
make  all-am
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/maxfieg/Desktop/FelixResearch/junk/hep_build2/HepMC2.04/HepMC'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/maxfieg/Desktop/FelixResearch/junk/hep_build2/HepMC2.04/HepMC'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/maxfieg/Desktop/FelixResearch/junk/hep_build2/HepMC2.04/HepMC'
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/maxfieg/Desktop/FelixResearch/junk/hep_build2/HepMC2.04/src'
/bin/bash ../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../HepMC -I.. -I..   -ansi -pedantic -Wall -g -O2 -MT CommonIO.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/CommonIO.Tpo -c -o CommonIO.lo CommonIO.cc
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../HepMC -I.. -I.. -ansi -pedantic -Wall -g -O2 -MT CommonIO.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/CommonIO.Tpo -c CommonIO.cc  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/CommonIO.o
In file included from ../HepMC/GenEvent.h:123:0,
                 from ../HepMC/CommonIO.h:15,
                 from CommonIO.cc:11:
../HepMC/GenVertex.h:173:71: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ was not declared in this scope
    public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag,HepMC::GenParticle*,ptrdiff_t>{
                                                                       ^~~~~~~~~
../HepMC/GenVertex.h:173:71: note: suggested alternatives:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/string:38:0,
                 from CommonIO.cc:8:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/c++config.h:232:28: note:   ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
   typedef __PTRDIFF_TYPE__ ptrdiff_t;
                            ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/c++config.h:232:28: note:   ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
In file included from ../HepMC/GenEvent.h:123:0,
                 from ../HepMC/CommonIO.h:15,
                 from CommonIO.cc:11:
../HepMC/GenVertex.h:173:80: error: template argument 3 is invalid
    public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag,HepMC::GenParticle*,ptrdiff_t>{
                                                                                ^
../HepMC/GenVertex.h:237:69: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ was not declared in this scope
    public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag,HepMC::GenVertex*,ptrdiff_t>{
                                                                     ^~~~~~~~~
../HepMC/GenVertex.h:237:69: note: suggested alternatives:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/string:38:0,
                 from CommonIO.cc:8:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/c++config.h:232:28: note:   ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
   typedef __PTRDIFF_TYPE__ ptrdiff_t;
                            ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/c++config.h:232:28: note:   ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
In file included from ../HepMC/GenEvent.h:123:0,
                 from ../HepMC/CommonIO.h:15,
                 from CommonIO.cc:11:
../HepMC/GenVertex.h:237:78: error: template argument 3 is invalid
    public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag,HepMC::GenVertex*,ptrdiff_t>{
                                                                              ^
../HepMC/GenVertex.h:307:64: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ was not declared in this scope
    public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag,GenParticle*,ptrdiff_t>{
                                                                ^~~~~~~~~
../HepMC/GenVertex.h:307:64: note: suggested alternatives:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/string:38:0,
                 from CommonIO.cc:8:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/c++config.h:232:28: note:   ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
   typedef __PTRDIFF_TYPE__ ptrdiff_t;
                            ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/c++config.h:232:28: note:   ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
In file included from ../HepMC/GenEvent.h:123:0,
                 from ../HepMC/CommonIO.h:15,
                 from CommonIO.cc:11:
../HepMC/GenVertex.h:307:73: error: template argument 3 is invalid
    public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag,GenParticle*,ptrdiff_t>{
                                                                         ^
In file included from ../HepMC/CommonIO.h:15:0,
                 from CommonIO.cc:11:
../HepMC/GenEvent.h:289:69: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ was not declared in this scope
    public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag,HepMC::GenVertex*,ptrdiff_t>{
                                                                     ^~~~~~~~~
../HepMC/GenEvent.h:289:69: note: suggested alternatives:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/string:38:0,
                 from CommonIO.cc:8:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/c++config.h:232:28: note:   ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
   typedef __PTRDIFF_TYPE__ ptrdiff_t;
                            ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/c++config.h:232:28: note:   ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
In file included from ../HepMC/CommonIO.h:15:0,
                 from CommonIO.cc:11:
../HepMC/GenEvent.h:289:78: error: template argument 3 is invalid
    public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag,HepMC::GenVertex*,ptrdiff_t>{
                                                                              ^
../HepMC/GenEvent.h:341:69: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ was not declared in this scope
    public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag,HepMC::GenVertex*,ptrdiff_t>{
                                                                     ^~~~~~~~~
../HepMC/GenEvent.h:341:69: note: suggested alternatives:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/string:38:0,
                 from CommonIO.cc:8:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/c++config.h:232:28: note:   ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
   typedef __PTRDIFF_TYPE__ ptrdiff_t;
                            ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/c++config.h:232:28: note:   ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
In file included from ../HepMC/CommonIO.h:15:0,
                 from CommonIO.cc:11:
../HepMC/GenEvent.h:341:78: error: template argument 3 is invalid
    public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag,HepMC::GenVertex*,ptrdiff_t>{
                                                                              ^
../HepMC/GenEvent.h:408:71: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ was not declared in this scope
    public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag,HepMC::GenParticle*,ptrdiff_t>{
                                                                       ^~~~~~~~~
../HepMC/GenEvent.h:408:71: note: suggested alternatives:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/string:38:0,
                 from CommonIO.cc:8:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/c++config.h:232:28: note:   ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
   typedef __PTRDIFF_TYPE__ ptrdiff_t;
                            ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/c++config.h:232:28: note:   ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
In file included from ../HepMC/CommonIO.h:15:0,
                 from CommonIO.cc:11:
../HepMC/GenEvent.h:408:80: error: template argument 3 is invalid
    public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag,HepMC::GenParticle*,ptrdiff_t>{
                                                                                ^
../HepMC/GenEvent.h:459:71: error: ‘ptrdiff_t’ was not declared in this scope
    public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag,HepMC::GenParticle*,ptrdiff_t>{
                                                                       ^~~~~~~~~
../HepMC/GenEvent.h:459:71: note: suggested alternatives:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/string:38:0,
                 from CommonIO.cc:8:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/c++config.h:232:28: note:   ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
   typedef __PTRDIFF_TYPE__ ptrdiff_t;
                            ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/c++config.h:232:28: note:   ‘std::ptrdiff_t’
In file included from ../HepMC/CommonIO.h:15:0,
                 from CommonIO.cc:11:
../HepMC/GenEvent.h:459:80: error: template argument 3 is invalid
    public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag,HepMC::GenParticle*,ptrdiff_t>{
                                                                                ^
CommonIO.cc: In member function ‘HepMC::HeavyIon* HepMC::CommonIO::read_heavy_ion(std::istream*)’:
CommonIO.cc:318:9: warning: converting ‘false’ to pointer type ‘HepMC::HeavyIon*’ [-Wconversion-null]
  return false;
         ^~~~~
CommonIO.cc:328:26: warning: converting ‘false’ to pointer type ‘HepMC::HeavyIon*’ [-Wconversion-null]
     if( nh == 0 ) return false;
                          ^~~~~
CommonIO.cc: In member function ‘HepMC::PdfInfo* HepMC::CommonIO::read_pdf_info(std::istream*)’:
CommonIO.cc:344:9: warning: converting ‘false’ to pointer type ‘HepMC::PdfInfo*’ [-Wconversion-null]
  return false;
         ^~~~~
CommonIO.cc:356:27: warning: converting ‘false’ to pointer type ‘HepMC::PdfInfo*’ [-Wconversion-null]
     if( id1 == 0 ) return false;
                           ^~~~~
CommonIO.cc: In member function ‘HepMC::GenVertex* HepMC::CommonIO::read_vertex(std::istream*, HepMC::TempParticleMap&)’:
CommonIO.cc:374:9: warning: converting ‘false’ to pointer type ‘HepMC::GenVertex*’ [-Wconversion-null]
  return false;
         ^~~~~
CommonIO.cc: In member function ‘HepMC::GenParticle* HepMC::CommonIO::read_particle(std::istream*, HepMC::TempParticleMap&)’:
CommonIO.cc:411:9: warning: converting ‘false’ to pointer type ‘HepMC::GenParticle*’ [-Wconversion-null]
  return false;
         ^~~~~
Makefile:478: recipe for target 'CommonIO.lo' failed
make[1]: *** [CommonIO.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/maxfieg/Desktop/FelixResearch/junk/hep_build2/HepMC2.04/src'
Makefile:397: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: The message "recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed" is extremely generic.  It conveys only that (1) the build system is based on the Autotools, and (2) the build failed.  It is not useful to look for solutions to your particular build problem by searching for that message.

Comment: It *is* useful to consider the first compilation error reported in `make`'s output, in light of warnings that reported for the same source file, so inasmuch as you have presented that, you have given us something we can work with.

Comment: The problem is that the source uses the symbol `ptrdiff_t` to refer to the type that (in C++) the compiler expects to be referred to as `std::ptrdiff_t`.  This undoubtedly worked with the compilers that this older version of the software was developed against, and you can probably make it work now by configuring with a compiler flag that request conformance with an older version of the language standard.  Someone more familiar with C++ could be more precise here, but something like configuring with `CXXFLAGS=gnu++03 ./configure` would probably be your best alternative.